# check internet connection doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, internet-connection

this is my code but it doesn't work correctly,it always returns true even when disable internet connection:

```
public boolean hasConnection(Context context) {

              /**
                *context.getsystemservice parameters:
                name: The name of the desired service. 
                Returns: The service or null if the name does not exist.
               */
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
              return true;
            }

            NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
              return true;
            }

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
              return true;
            }

            return false;
          }//end of hasConnection class
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` permission?

Comment: no,i didn't miss the permission

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
public boolean CheckInternet() 
{
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    // Here if condition check for wifi and mobile network is available or not.
    // If anyone of them is available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;

    if (wifi.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else if (mobile.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to see what this line of code do

```
  NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }
```

because above two conditions are fine and try removing the above mentioned code i think it would work..

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested if any kind of network is connected at all, you don't need extra code:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return (ni != null) && ni.isConnected();
```

Comment: @jaradat What happens ?

Comment: it always returns true even there's no internet connection

Comment: @jaradat switch to airplane mode, then check.

Comment: @jaradat This is the standard way, it should work, same as shown in android documentation : http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: what do you mean by airplane mode and how to switch to it?